# Can i run my facebook apps from local host

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

Problem: Can i run my facebook apps from local host.

Description: I want to get facebook wall posts on my website page. For testing, i created a facebook app and put site url as "http:localhost:8088/fb/" nd app domain as "localhost". Now i want to get user id so that i can access facebook wall posts.But all am getting is user id equals to zero.I have checked it so many times. but everything seems to be correct. So i want to know that can we use local host as site url?? Can i get user id by running my code from local host. Below is my code.

```
<?php 
include_once "facebook.php";



$facebook = new Facebook(array(
               'appId' => '<app id>',
                'secret' => '<app secret>',
                'cookie' => true,
            ));

$uid = $facebook->getUser();
echo $uid;
$me = null;
if ($uid) {
  try {

   $me = $facebook->api('/me');
    $feed = $facebook->api('/me/feed/');
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
  }
}

$params = array(
  'scope' => 'read_stream',
  'redirect_uri' => 'http://localhost:8088/fb/feeds.php'
);
if ($uid) {

    $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
} 
else {
    $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl($params);
}

?>
<!doctype html>
<html xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
  <head>
    <title>php-sdk</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <?php if($uid)

    {
    ?>
    <a href="<?php echo $logoutUrl; ?>">Logout</a>
    <?php
  }
else
{
?>
<a href="<?php echo $loginUrl; ?>">Login</a>
<?php
}   
     ?>

    <?php if ($me): ?>
    <?php
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($feed);
    echo "</pre>";
    ?>
    <?php endif ?>
 </body>
</html>
```

Please tell me what is the problem here. Is there any settings tht i need to perform. I will be very thankful.

Comment: Please don't post your app id and app secret in your posts. It may cause you trouble if someone used it for malicious purposes

Comment: Also I would appreciate if you could refrain to post [multiple](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/13599758/getuser-method-of-facebook-php-sdk-always-returns-0) times for the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can run your app from localhost environment. You have done everything correct except that you don't need to add localhost in the app domain and your site url should be

> http:// localhost:8088 /fb/

instead of "http:localhost:8088/fb/"

Comment: Thank you for the help. But even i have used "http://localhost:8088/fb/" as site url. It was just a typing mistake. I have also removed localhost in the app domain. But still there is no success... I have been trying for this since a week. But haven't found any solution yet. Dont know where is the problem.

Comment: Are you getting the login part correct ? I mean whether you are able to login with the link that you generate?

Comment: yes. i am able to login but when i am redirected to my url, i dont get user id.. Even after authorization of the app, user id is zero.

Comment: I tried your code with mine app id and secret on my localhost and it works absolutely fine, retrieves the id and feed.

Comment: Please tell me one thing. Do  you have SSL (https://) on your localhost?? I am using (http://) as my redirect url. Are you also using http:// for redirect url??

Comment: I am using http://localhost to test, and my local system has IIS as the server at default port. Could you change your site URL to just http://localhost:8088/ and retry

Answer (score 1):

A better way to test out the Facebook api on localhost is to first create a virtual host for your web application like yourapp.local and then set the URLs in your Facebook app information accordingly. You can create separate Facebook apps for local and remote sites.

Answer (score 0):

You can for the most part.
Facebook apps which are just iframes don't need to connect to your host - only you/your browsers does.

Two things to watch out for:

1. Make sure you have SSL (https://) on your localhost. If not, disable SSL in your test Facebook account settings.
2. One situation where Facebook will need to access your host include sharing URLs or images that are hosted in your app. Use external placeholders when testing your local app.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you can't do that if you have facebook aggregations ( Objects+actions) in your app. Because they need to be accessed directly by facebook

Comment: i dont have facebook aggregations. I have simply created facebook app.